# Результаты поиска на этой же странице Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно реализовать вывод результатов поиска, вместо блока популярных постов, на этой же странице, без переадресации. Подскажите как сделать. Или хотя бы в каком векторе искать

Comment: Смотрите в сторону Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать по следуещей логике:

- Создать функцию, которая будет вызыватся через Ajax и отдавать ответ\результаты поиска
- Добавить в файлы темы js скрипт, который будет подключатся на нужной странице, при кликне на кнопку поиска брать значение что ищут с строки ввода, дали отсылать запрос к нашей функции, написаной выше, и на основе рузультата делать следуещее:

  Установить в блок популярных постов пустой html или вовсе скрыть его
  Добавить в блок популярных постов ответ от функции, или если мы использували наш другой блок сделать наш другой бдлок видимым и добавить внутрь наш результат поиска.

В общем, создать Ajax функцию и js скрипт обработчик действий.